# How to segment a string following a requirement

Tags: string, algorithm

I am trying to resolve but I couldn't find a good algorithm. I have a sting as this

```
“jesuisfrancaisdoriginemalienneetjhabitelesetatsunis”
```

and from it I want to split as follow

```
“jesuisfr”
“ancaisdo”
“riginema”
“lienneet”
“jhabitel”
“setatsun”
“is”
```

**Requirement**

- The size of the segment is determined by the length of the string
- `length of segment >= number of line and length of segment - number of line <= 1`

Following this requirement, the string above is 52 length. So `length of segment = 8 and number of line = 7`

My problem now is how do I apply the given requirement to any string of size from 50 to infinity? What can be the algorithm or pseudo-code? Be it in JavaScript or any language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the `number of line` and `length of segment`  will  depend on the square root of the the given string length.

let,
square_root= square root of string length
so `number of line` is square_root
and `length of segment` will be either square_root or square_root+1.

if square_root*square_root is equal to string length then `length of segment` will be square_root otherwise square_root+1.

Comment: @bam please let me know if you have any confusion

Answer (score 0):

JS version:

```js
let str = 'jesuisfrancaisdoriginemalienneetjhabitelesetatsunis';
let length = str.length;

let segment = 1, line;
while(segment < length)
{
    line = Math.ceil(length / segment);
 if(segment >= line && segment - line <= 1)
    {
      break;
    }
    segment ++;  
}

let arr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < line; i ++){
    let newStr = str.substr(0, segment);
    arr.push(newStr);
    str = str.substr(segment);
}

console.log('segment=' + segment, 'line=' + line);
console.log('string length = ' + length);
console.log('result = ' + arr);
```